# Resubmitting same sql file in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

The following error is being generated when i try to execute a rather large sql file using phpmyadmin.

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.

But i dont see any viable way to resubmit and continue from that situation. There is a 'Back' link which takes me back to import page but i have to start over again, and as expected, execution gets stuck again similarly

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with phpMyAdmin, but IIRC there is a text field when you click that "Back" link that is automatically populated with a starting position. In essence, when you re-upload the file, it will skip a certain number of queries and just carry on where it left off. If it hits the timeout again, that means there was still too much work to be done. Hitting back again should update that text field with a new (larger) offset for the next upload.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default maximum query for phpMyAdmin is around 300 seconds.  If your query is taking longer, it will time out (as per the error detail).

To override this, you'd need to add a line (or edit, if it's already there) into `config.inc.php`, which lives in the base dir of the phpMyAdmin folder, as per one of the below examples:

```
\\ Default value is probably 300
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;


\\ Turn it off completely by setting it to zero
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;


\\ Or just crank it up a little
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;
```

...then restart to put the settings in place